# How to concatenate two or more .wav file in android?

Tags: android, io, wav, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

When iam merging two .wav file it is not merging the file and the file iam giving into FileOutStream i mean name of new merged file it keep on increasing the size never stop,size goes in GB's and at some point app force closes.

```
    private String combine(ArrayList<String> combineFile) {
    FileInputStream in1 = null;
    FileInputStream in2 = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE;
    long byteRate = Constants.RecordingConstants.RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < combineFile.size()-1; i++) {

        try {
            in1 = new FileInputStream(combineFile.get(i));
            in2 = new FileInputStream(combineFile.get(i + 1));
            out = new FileOutputStream(getFileName());
            totalAudioLen = in1.getChannel().size() + in2.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

            while (in1.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }
            while (in2.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }
            in1.close();
            in2.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return combineFile.get(i);
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1; // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (channels * 16 / 8); // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = Constants.RecordingConstants.RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}

    public String getFileName() {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    fileName = getString(R.string.file_name_suffix) + "_" + date + ".wav";
    ;
    File file = new File(filePath, Constants.RecordingConstants.RECORDER_FOLDER);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
}
```

Comment: That's a strange loop. If you're processing two elements from `combineFile` per iteration, then why are you only incrementing `i` by 1 per iteration? Where is the implementation for `getFileName`? If it returns the same filename every time then you obviously shouldn't be creating a new `FileOutputStream` or write a new WAV header for every iteration. Also, you seem to be assuming that just because `read` doesn't return `-1` that you've read exactly `bufferSize` bytes, but you may have read less than that.

Comment: I have edited the question and add getFileName() implementation check it now and I'm incrementing i by 1 because if there are two files then combineFile(i) combineFile(i+1) concatenate 1st and 2nd file in ArrayList and after loop break it should result me final wav file.